# Jenkins freestyle project not getting triggered by github webhook

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins

So, this is what I've done so far:

- Created GitHub personal access token with God's permissions (except delete repos)
- Associated personal access token in Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System> GitHub , I test it and says "Credentials verified for user dim_user, rate limit: 4998"
  [image]
- Checked "Manage hooks"
- In Source Code Management  I set it like this:

  - Repository URL: `git@databases.github.com:ORG_NAME/bootcamp_databases`
  - Credentials: `- none -` (I'm using local's Git config file and id_rsa private key)
- Also in "Build triggers" I've checked "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling" which refers to the old "Build when a change is pushed to GitHub"
  [image]
- I am able to Manually build it and it works perfectly (gets source code from GitHub and deploys everything)
- In the project's GitHub Hook Log it shows: "Polling has not run yet"
  [image]
- GitHub recent Webhook deliveries are successful

[image]

Jenkins Logs (jenkins.err)

```
Jul 17, 2019 10:11:31 AM org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.webhook.subscriber.DefaultPushGHEventSubscriber onEvent
INFO: Received PushEvent for https://github.com/ORG_NAME/bootcamp_databases from XXX.XX.115.71 ? http://XXXXXXXX.ngrok.io:8080/github-webhook/
```

Project item: Freestyle

Jenkins Version: 2.176.1

I've tried these and did not help:

- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-35132
- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41377

**Actual**:

[image]

**Expected**:

To actually fetch the code when pushing to GitHub and triggering the jenkins build.

What am I missing, all of the above points were solutions on other stackoverflow questions but so far not good.

Comment: For webhook trigger the project has to have run at least once, i think jenkins then records the scm urls to watch for on the job. Did you run the job once after setup?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I think your error is here:

- Build triggers" I've checked "GitHub hook trigger for *GITScm polling*

In Jenkins an others c.i servers there are two techniques to *detect* scm source changes:

- Polling: Jenkins *asks*  periodically to github if source code has changes ( i.e git clone every minute and compare )
- webhook:  Github *notify* to your Jenkins when an event is detected in git platform( github, bitbucket etc). This is more *cheap* and does not need check changes at predefined interval (polling)

My advice is to try with webhooks instead scm polling. Also polling is an outdated technique.

Comment: thanks, however that is exactly what I'm doing, I'm using webhooks, in fact in GitHub I've configured the payload (http://my-jenkins-server.com/github-webhook/), would you please specify which option in build triggers corresponds to webhook? my understanding was that I was following the Manual mode of  "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling"  specified in https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin#GitHubPlugin-GitHubhooktriggerforGITScmpolling

Comment: I am sorry they are downvoting your answer, I read carefully your answer 3 years ago, and I was able to solve this problem but , I can't recall what it was honestly but I remember going with SCM Polling. I will mark your answer as answer if it helps but honestly and to be transparent your answer did not provide my solution, but I thank you for providing more context and info .

Comment: No worries. If you find the solution to your own question, don't forget to share the solution as an answer.